# SQL parsing for logical equality

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, algorithm, parsing

I have a problem and was hoping if someone here can help. I have a thousands of SQL statements in a file and have to identify duplicates based on logical equality of WHERE clause. e.g.

**SQL1**

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1='A' AND col2='B';
```

**SQL2**

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col2='B' AND col1='A';
```

In the above example **SQL1** & **SQL2** are same. This is a simple illustration of the problem.
I am looking for pointers on different approaches I can take here.
I have tried using [Apache Calcite](https://calcite.apache.org/) as an option that gives me the tree to compare is the option that I am leaning towards right now but wanted to see if there is something obvious out there that I do not know off.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [so] isn't a free coding service. What have you tried so far, and why isn't it working? You've tagged [tag:java], so I *assume* the solution needs to use Java? What is your existing Java Code?

Comment: What you're asking for is a development effort that would take many, many years. Look at 'query optimizers' in your friendly neighbourhood open source db impl (may I suggest you look at the postgres source code?) - it's incredibly complicated. It starts by needing to parse SQL, which is a notoriously hard language to parse, and then doing some seriously complicated work simplifying and rewriting queries. You can either use psql's query optimizer, which requires familiarizing yourself with that code base and writing it in C, or, you can...

Comment: ... severely restrict your requirements here and [A] add a ton of caveats of exactly what the SQL is supposed to look like, and document that if the SQL does not look like this, that your 'dupe finder' will not work, and [B] limit, severely, what your dupe finder can actually find. Once you've written down what you do and don't want to restrict, this question could possibly turn into a manweek project. And from there, possibly something that is suitable as StackOverflow question.

Comment: I have looked at apache calcite and use its parser to get the syntax tree and compare as 1 of the options, I should have added that in the original comment :). You guys are brutal here

Comment: Execute them and see if they return exactly the same result ;)

Comment: Just how complicated these logical equalities can be? Is it just a matter of order or conditions in the where clause of a singe table select? Or could you have joins involved?

Comment: @Rajat  Yes there can be joins and all kind of logical operators

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is an easy solution to your problem but I will suggest a technique that could help you identify some duplicates.

Get yourself a massive copy of the database then write a program that runs the queries one by one, comparing the results. If the results are similar, you flag the queries as a potential duplicate.

You can use the following criteria to determine if the resultset of `SELECT` queries are the same:

```
if the number of rows is the same
->and number of columns is the same
->and the actual data is the same
->then its most likely that the queries are the same
```